# MS Access continuous subform not populating when returning to the associated record

Tags: ms-access

I have a single form data-entry application "Physical" which contains a tab control housing particular subforms.  tabBlank is just an empty starting tab that is displayed until the user enters the necessary information.  Based upon the information entered in the top row of fields, a corresponding tab (tabPhysicalGillnet, tabPhysicalSeine, tabPhysicalTrawl) is activated to continue data-entry that is appropriate only for that information.  This data is all directly linked to a single table, "Physical".  Once the necessary data for one of those tabs is entered, the user is then presented with "tabCatch" to enter 2nd tier-level data (one-to-many) into a continuous subform, "frmCatch", whose data is linked to a second table, "Catch".  For each record entered in "Catch", 3rd-tier level data (also one-to-many) can be entered into subform, "frmLengths" which is linked to a table, "Lengths".  Initial data-entry proceeds as expected: The user enters a species into "Catch" along with its values and proceeds to enter lengths for that species.  There is only one line of code on this form that sets the focus to the Lengths subform once the user enters the species information:

```
Private Sub Notes_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
       If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then Forms!Physical!frmLengths.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Once the user enters the lengths, they can enter another species, enter those lengths, and so on.  The problem occurs if the user switches back to a previous species record: the Lengths subform does not repopulate with the existing values.  However, any additional values entered are appended in the Lengths table correctly, they just can't be seen if the current record changes.

I have tried the requery and refresh methods of the Lengths subform with no effect.
[image]

Comment: This sounds like the "Data Entry" property of the Lengths subform is "Yes".  If so, switch it to "No" and see whether it then behaves as you wish.